# How to change default Requested URL of XAMPP i.e localhost:80/xampp

Tags: xampp

I installed XAMPP on windows 7, Apache was not running because Port 80 was not released. I changed it to 81 in “httpd” (C:\xampp\apache\conf) and now its working.
Issue is that every time xampp control panel opens localhost:80/xampp and then I have to manually change it to  localhost:81/xampp. Please guide me, where I have to make changing to make default Requested URL localhost:81/xampp ?
I’m a beginner ok and didn't get help by random searching. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

right click on xampp icon in taskbar

click show/hide

click config in apache field
 select apache (httpd.conf)

edit lines

```
#Listen 0.0.0.0:80
#Listen [::]:80
Listen 80
```

change "80" with port you want apache to use

save file, press 'start' apache

Comment: I appreciate your kind concern, thanks for giving time. 
Actually I had done those changing in httpd.conf file
#Listen 0.0.0.0:81
#Listen [::]:81
Listen 81
……………….. plus
ServerName localhost:81 
Problem is when I press “Admin” button in xampp CPanel it gives 404-Not found Error. Error detail shows 
Requested URL http://localhost:80/xampp/

And to get desired page I rewrite the URL “http://localhost:81”
Question is, where should I make changing so that on clicking CPanel apache “Admin” button, localhost:81 browse ?

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is in the xampp/index.php file for the menu links if you know php and html this should be easy enough to do. If you do not, go to http://w3schools.com to freshen up on html and php. hope this helps ;-)